# Superscript cents in dynamic text string using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, superscript

I'm trying to superscript the cents in some prices; the prices are dynamic so I can't manually add the sup tags in the HTML.

As far as I know, the prices should be formatted like "3,99 €" but I don't want anything to break if they're changed to something like "€3.99" in the future.

I was trying to use a RegEx like

```js
  var matcher = /(\.|\,)\d{2}(?![\d])/;
  return price.replace(matcher, '<sup>' + matcher + '</sup>');
```

but I haven't quite figured out how to get only the cents value wrapped between the superscript tags.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it: `(\d[,.])(\d{2})(?!\d)`. An extra capture group is needed to allow more characters to be matched while not being replaced (a workaround for positive lookbehind).

```js
var regex = /(\d[,.])(\d{2})(?!\d)/g;
var str = 'Test test test 100,99€ test 2.116.600,99€ test € 2,50 test.';

console.log(str.replace(regex, '$1<sup>$2</sup>'));
```

Explanation:

```
(\d[,.]) | Capture a digit followed by "," or "."
(\d{2})  | Capture the two cents digits
(?!\d)   | Ensure a digit doesn't follow the previous capture
```

#### [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/SfEySK/4)

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is amazing and very close to what I need.  The only problem is this seems to fail with longer numbers like 1,000 and up.  Is there any way to fix for that scenario, too?

Comment: Ah, completely skipped over longer numbers. Fixed it.

Comment: Sorry, I ran this through https://regexr.com/ to get a better understanding of how this is working, and it game me a warning that the "positive lookbehind" feature may not be supported in all browsers.  So then I tested the code in Firefox and Safari, and realized the superscripting isn't working anywhere but Chrome.  Is there any way to get this working across browsers?  Thank you again.

Comment: Not only does JS not support lookbehind assertions, it does not support variable width lookbehind assertions either.

Comment: JavaScript [supports lookbehind assertions](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md), but not all environments support it yet. That's an oversight on my part.

Comment: @emma Updated to remove the positive lookbehind.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your help!  This looks great.  Quick question... when replacing the string, would you mind explaining how the '$1<sup>$2</sup>' part is working?  I just want to be sure I have a complete understanding.

Comment: Sure! In the replacement string, you can use `$<num>` to insert captured characters in the regex. So `$1` is the captured characters from the `(\d[,.])` part and `$2` is the captured characters from the `(\d{2})` part.